# How to get value of selected listbox item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm loading data from an xml file into a listbox . Here is my xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstSearchCategory" FontFamily="Arial Black" 
         VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="25,69,19,10" Height="264">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel >
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Height="100" Width="100" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Image>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Name}" 
                           FontSize="30" Foreground="Black" Margin="140,-100,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}" FontSize="24" 
                           Foreground="Black" Margin="10,-10,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                           Foreground="Red" Margin="300,-25,0,16"/>
                <Rectangle Width="500"  Fill="Black" Height="0.5"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This is working fine. Now I want that when I select any listbox item, I get its respective values i.e image, price, category etc. How can i do this ? Help

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the selected item in a ListBox Event and get the DataTemplate from the ListBox (as seen on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/95cc3b53-eb31-44ef-b006-82c738bcf5fa/how-to-get-datatemplate-values-for-selected-listitem-of-listbox-in-code-behind)):

```
private void lstEvents_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBoxItem lbi = (lstEvents.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(lstEvents.SelectedIndex)) as ListBoxItem;
            ContentPresenter cp = GetFrameworkElementByName<ContentPresenter>(lbi);
            DataTemplate dt = lstEvents.ItemTemplate;
            Label l = (dt.FindName("lblEventId", cp)) as Label;
            MessageBox.Show(l.Content.ToString());   
        }
```

Comment: its giving error at GetFrameworkElementByName and FindName

Comment: Could you have  look at the following example. http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/listbox-windows-phone/implementing-a-custom-data-template-selector-in-windows-phone-8s-listbox-control/

Answer (score 0):

You need generate `Tap = "lstSearchCategory_Tap"` in your XAML file and below code in `.cs` file

```
private void lstSearchCategory_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ListBox ListBoxSelecteditem = (ListBox)sender;
        YourModel model = (YourModel)ListBoxSelecteditem.SelectedItem;            

        string name = model.Name;
        string cat = model.Category;
        .......

        string ControlName = ((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)
                             (((System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)(e)).OriginalSource)).Name;
        if (ControlName.ToLower() != "name".ToLower())
        {
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ListBox Tap="lstSearchCategory_Tap" x:Name="lstSearchCategory">
```

and than on tap event add this

```
    var selected = (classname)lstSearchCategory.SelectedValue;
   MessegeBox.Show(selected.Name + selected.Price);
```

here class-name is name of class where you are binding the name, price etc values

Answer (score -1):

If you fill your `ListBox` via binding, you should have some property lile `SelectedItem` in your view model. So the currently selected item should always be stored in the viewmodel for easy access. Just add a binding to `SelectedItem` in your viewmodel and every thing should work.

Comment: Can you show  me the code ? I'm confuse how to get selected category etc